# Customize UITabBarItem in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to solve a frontend problem. I need to customize a UITabBarItem with this stackView
-Image
-Text
-Image

[image]

I know that the Standard UITabBarItem has only the properties of an image, a selected image and a text label.
I can't put the text inside the image because the app has more languages so I can't have an image per language.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You **can indeed have** localised images [documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/localizing-assets-in-a-catalog).
Apart from this, there's not much you can do with `UITabBarItem`.